# How would you make an iframe's height always extend to the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, height

I want to generate an iframe whose height will extend to the bottom of the browser window. If the user changes the height of the browser, then the iframe's height should change dynamically as well. However, I'd like for the iframe to have a minimum height past which it would not shrink any further. How would I do this?

Comment: @Cfreak well, admittedly nothing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something very similar. 
1) Get a hold of the window resize event (I am using jQuery)

```
$(window).resize(function(){});
```

2) Pop in what you want your actions to be. For me I was setting a height explicitly on the body of the document so my CSS of height:100% on an inner container would take hold. You could do anything within the function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('body').height($(document).height());
});
```

My markup :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="full-height">Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS :

```
body {position:relative;}
.full-height {height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what you're working with, but this will hopefully point you in the right direction.

```
iframe {
  height:100%;
  min-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried putting the iframe inside a wrapper div

```
<div id="iframediv" style="min-height:500; overflow:scroll">
    <iframe src="http://google.com">­ </iframe>
</div>
```

It's worth a shot.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't help in any way.  the parent div isn't affecting the iframe.  The iframe needs it's own size declared.  Plus the dimension on min-height would need units to even do anything.

Comment: well obviusly he wouldnt use that same code, that was just an example. How can I live from now on knowing that i got a -1 for trying to help...alas, so long cruel world

Comment: The help needs to be useful and accurate.  This isn't either.  That's what the voting system is for to help future readers know which pieces of help are useful and which are not.  If you aren't super experienced, then I'd suggest trying the things you recommend to make sure they work.  It's easy to verify things work in http://jsfiddle.net.